# Proof unclear: showing inequality is sharp

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal J(f, X \sim P)=\mathbb E[f(X)]-f(\mu)$, where $f$ is a function, $X$ is a random variable with $\mathbb E[X]=\mu$ and $P$ is its distribution.

Consider the following statement:

[image]

The author then stated that for functions that satisfy the conditions in Theorem 1, there exists a $M'>0$ such that 
$$|\mathbb E[f(X)]-f(\mu)|\leq M'\sigma_n^\alpha$$
for sufficiently small $\sigma_n$.

> There is no proof for this claim. And I don't really understand the claim. We simply write $M'$ instead of $M(1+\sigma_n^{n-\alpha})$?

Next, we show that the inequality modulo the constant $M'$ is sharp:

[image]

> Why is $|\mathcal J(f, X\sim P)|\geq M\int |X-\mu|^\alpha dP(X)$ in the last line true? He somehow uses the condition $|f(x)-f(\mu)| \geq M|x-\mu|^\alpha$ but I can't understand how.

Comment: What are the $\sigma$'s?

Comment: @Jose27 $\sigma_p=\sqrt[p]{\mathbb E[|X-\mu|^p]}$

Comment: @Jose27 Any idea?